# Trying to get a median, given a list. Trying to use toArray. Not sure what is wrong

Tags: c#

Here's what I have but I don't know why it's wrong:

```
public static int findMedian(List<int> arr)
    {
        int[] asArray = arr.ToArray();
        int[] arrSorted = Array.Sort(asArray);
        float midIndex = 0;
        int arrLength = arrSorted.Length;
        if (arrLength % 2 == 1)
        {
            midIndex = Math.Ceiling(arrLength / 2);
            return arrSorted[midIndex];
        }
        else
        {
            return (arrSorted[Math.Ceiling(arrLength / 2)] + arrSorted[Math.Floor(arrLength / 2)]) / 2;
        }
    }
```

It says "Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'int[]' " but I dont know where the 'void' is coming from.

Comment: `Array.Sort(asArray)` doesn't return anything, it sorts in situ. However, just at a glance, that is only one of many problems your code has. e.g. `midIndex` should not be a float

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.sort?view=net-6.0

Comment: Oh. I'm new to this and I cant get a response from my teacher so I thought SO could help.
I've looked up how to convert from list to array and that's what pulled up. I guess I misunderstood how to use it.

Comment: FYI: `arrLength / 2` is integer division, so if you do something like `5/2`, you'll get `2`. `Math.Ceiling(2)` will return `2.0` You can force `5/2` to result in a `double` by changing it to `5/2.0` (i.e. `arrLength / 2.0`).

Comment: Thanks. That cleared up a few other errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed the `Array.Sort` method sorts the existing array and doesn't return a new one. That's easily fixed by using a method that does return a new one.

Next, there's no need to use `Math.Ceiling` - which is causing you to use `float`. You can just use integer math.

Try this solution:

```
public static int FindMedian(List<int> source)
{
    int[] sorted = source.OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();
    return (sorted[(sorted.Length - 1) / 2] + sorted[sorted.Length / 2]) / 2;
}
```

When source has an odd number of elements this code performs a redundant addition and division, so you could use this instead, although the result is identical:

```
public static int FindMedian(List<int> source)
{
    int[] sorted = source.OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();
    int i = (sorted.Length - 1) / 2;
    int j = sorted.Length / 2;
    return i == j ? sorted[i] : (sorted[i] + sorted[j]) / 2;
}
```

Or, a more explicit method:

```
public static int FindMedian(List<int> source)
{
    int[] sorted = source.OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();
    if (sorted.Length % 2 == 1)
    {
        return sorted[sorted.Length / 2];
    }
    else
    {
        return (sorted[sorted.Length / 2] + sorted[sorted.Length / 2 - 1]) / 2;
    }
}
```

For all three of these methods, I can test with this data:

```
var samples = new int[][]
{
    new int[] { 10 },
    new int[] { 10, 20 },
    new int[] { 10, 20, 30 },
    new int[] { 10, 20, 30, 40 },
};
```

I get `10, 15, 20, 25` as the median for each line respectively.

Comment: Be sure to guard against `source.Count == 0`, where the median is not defined, and this code would access element 0 of a List with no elements.

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming from your `int[] arrSorted = Array.Sort(asArray);` line, `Array.Sort()` sorts the array passed into its first parameter, doesn't return anything. So changing the line to just `Array.Sort(asArray);` should fix it.

Comment: That fixed almost all of it. Thank you!
Now I just have to figure out why my else statement  results in "Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'int'."